# Restarting signalr hubconnection

Tags: vb.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm self hosting owin and using signalr in a wpf application to let a user access a real time webview. I am able to start the server and create a hub connection using this code.

```
Public Sub SatartWebUi()
    _server = WebApp.Start(Of Startup)(Url)
    _hubConnection = New HubConnection(Url)
    _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myHub")
    _hubConnection.Start().Wait()
End Sub
```

Then some time later the user can stop the server using this code which also works.

```
Public Sub EndWebUi()
    _hubConnection.Stop()
    _server.Dispose()
End Sub
```

My problem is the user should be able to restart the server. When I call the function `StartWebUi` to try and start it again the line `_hubConnection.Start().Wait()` causes this error

```
TimeoutException: Transport timed out trying to connect
```

The Error Log

```
    App Exception ; Exception details = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The operation was canceled. [   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageReader.<ReadMessageAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted) ] : Inner Exception = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] : Inner Exception = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] : Inner Exception = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The 'System.Net.WebSockets.ServerWebSocket' instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into the 'Aborted' state. [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfAborted(Boolean aborted, Exception innerException) ] : Inner Exception = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [ ] : Inner Exception = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageReader.<ReadMessageAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] : Inner Exception = The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request [   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = The 'System.Net.WebSockets.ServerWebSocket' instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into the 'Aborted' state. [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfAborted(Boolean aborted, Exception innerException)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] : Inner Exception = An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  [ ] : Inner Exception = An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection [   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext() ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:49 AM
WebUi.exe Error: 0 : Error while closing the websocket: System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The 'System.Net.WebSockets.ServerWebSocket' instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into the 'Aborted' state. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<WriteAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfAborted(Boolean aborted, Exception innerException)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.<>c.<<CloseAsync>b__13_0>d.MoveNext()
App Exception ; Exception details = An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method. [   at System.Net.ChunkParser.SetReadParameters(Byte[] userBuffer, Int32 userBufferOffset, Int32 userBufferCount) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:54 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method. [   at System.Net.ChunkParser.SetReadParameters(Byte[] userBuffer, Int32 userBufferOffset, Int32 userBufferCount)
   at System.Net.ChunkParser.Read(Byte[] userBuffer, Int32 userBufferOffset, Int32 userBufferCount)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ReadWithoutValidation(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean abortOnError) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:54 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. [   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:54 AM
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. [   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:54 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. [   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__43_1(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:54 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. [   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:59 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = Cannot access a disposed object.
App Exception ; Exception details = The request was aborted: The request was canceled. [   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:59 AM
App Exception ; Exception details = One or more errors occurred. [   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) ] : Inner Exception = Transport timed out trying to connect [ ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:59 AM
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
App Exception ; Exception details = One or more errors occurred. [   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) ] : Inner Exception = Transport timed out trying to connect [ ] ; Error ; 2/12/2018 8:42:59 AM
An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
One or more errors occurred.

The program '[16776] WebUi.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: you shouldn't dispose the server

Comment: or at least if you dispose the server you should restart the server also when you want to start another connection

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml the 4 lines are in a method called `StartWebUi` that gets called not just the `_hubConnection.Start.Wait()`

Comment: Do you get any errors on WebApp.Start....?

Comment: errors in the log or in eventvwr ?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml I added the error log. When I call the `StartWebUi` function the second time it does start and If I have commented out the `_hubConnection.Start.Wait()` I can browse to the site